# Angular, how to correctly map REST Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new at angular and am having a little trouble mapping objects from the rest calls via a service i created.

I have a service

```
var teacherServices = angular.module('teacherServices', ['ngResource']);

teacherServices.factory('Items', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('/class/item/:class_id', {Id: "@Id"}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{class_id:''}, isArray:false}
    });
}]);
```

And i am attempting to get a list of the objects using

```
teacher_app.controller('ItemsCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', 'Items', function($scope, $route, Items) {
Items.get({class_id : $route.current.params.classId}, function(response) {
    $scope.items = response.items;
    $scope.items[0].$save();  //Does not exist
});
```

}]);

I have two questions

1) How would I correctly map the objects so that it has all the default functions like $save()

2) How would I create my custom functions for the objects

Thank you

Comment: You have specified `isArray:false` so try `$scope.items.$save()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chandermani you got me thinking in the right direction!

The issue was that i was using the standard get method not the 'query' method I defined in the service. I also changed the response call to be be an array instead of an object holding an array.

```
teacherServices.factory('Items', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('/class/item/:class_id', {Id: "@Id"}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{class_id:''}, isArray:true}
    });
}]);


teacher_app.controller('ItemsCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', 'Items', function($scope, $route, Items) {
Items.query({class_id : $route.current.params.classId}, function(response) {
    $scope.items = response;
    console.log($scope.items);
});
```

}]);